# Need help with simple collision detection algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Alright, so my simple collision detection algorithm isn't working. It always activates (Unless the player doesn't have any collisions on his x and/or y plains).

Well, here's the code:

```
collisionCheck: function(bArray){
    for(var i = 0; i < bArray.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < bArray[i].length; j++){
            if(bArray[i][j].getType() != 0){
                if((bArray[i][j].getX() > this.x && bArray[i][j].getX() < this.x + this.width) ||
                    (bArray[i][j].getX() + blockSize > this.x && bArray[i][j].getX() + blockSize < this.x + this.width) &&
                    (bArray[i][j].getY() > this.y && bArray[i][j].getY() < this.y + this.height) || 
                    (bArray[i][j].getY() + blockSize > this.y && bArray[i][j].getY() + blockSize < this.y + this.height)){
                    this.x = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See any reason on why it's activating when it shouldn't?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
collisionCheck: function(bArray){
  for(var i=0,len=bArray.length; i<len; ++i){
    for(var j=0,len2=bArray[i].length; j<len2; ++j){
      if(!bArray[i][j].getType()) continue;
      var x = bArray[i][j].getX(), y = bArray[i][j].getY();
      var x2 = x+blockSize, y2 = y+blockSize;
      var overlapping = (x2>this.x) && (x<(this.x+this.width)) && (y2>this.y) && (y<(this.y+this.height));
      if (overlapping) this.x = 0; // I don't know why you'd do this, but it's what you have
    }
  }
  // Should this function return anything?
}
```

To answer your question as to why your current logic is not correct, let's focus on one problem. Your logic says basically that there is a collision if:

> (YourLeftEdgeIsPastMyLeftEdge AND YourLeftEdgeIsNotPastMyRightEdge)
>   OR
>   ((Something AND Something) AND (Something AND Something))
>   OR
>   (Something AND Something)

The middle line is because `&&` has [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `||`, causing the middle two lines of your condition to be clumped together.

Looking that that, we can see that a the collision can succeed by checking only the horizontal placement of the two items, which is clearly a mistake.

The logic I have in my answer is basically that two objects do ***not*** overlap if:

- A. The right edge of one is to the left of the left edge of the other, OR
- B. The left edge of one is to the right of the right edge of the other, OR
- C. The bottom edge of one is above the top edge of the other, OR
- D. The top edge of one is below the bottom edge of the other.

[De Morgan's Laws](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDe_Morgan%27s_laws&ei=X709TaS7O4z6sAPw5ZT_Ag&usg=AFQjCNEL7A8w_gruPMzeBOWR5sUn3HVYwQ) say that `!(A || B || C || D)` is the same as `(!A && !B && !C && !D)`, and so we can say that two objects ***do*** overlap if:

- A. The right edge of one is to the *right* of the left edge of the other, AND
- B. The left edge of one is to the *left* of the right edge of the other, AND
- C. The bottom edge of one is *below* the top edge of the other, AND
- D. The top edge of one is *above* the bottom edge of the other.

And this results in the code I supplied:
`(x2>this.x) && (x<(this.x+this.width)) && (y2>this.y) && (y<(this.y+this.height))`

Answer (score 0):

```
function spritecollision(x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2){
    if(x2<(x1+w1)&&(x2+w2)>x1&&y2<(y1+h1)&&(y2+h2)>y1)return 1;
}
```

So, if you want it to always activate EXCEPT when there's a collision, use `!spritecollision`.

Source: http://nextgengame.webs.com/fun.htm

EDIT: This is the best answer. It's perfect.

Comment: Separate from validating your boolean logic, this is shorter and better: `return x2<(x1+w1) && (x2+w2)>x1 && y2<(y1+h1) && (y2+h2)>y1;`

Comment: No, I only work with type Number. Who needs boolean? This is MY function, and I use it on my site.